# Calculating exactly how much etherum I need to send to wallet to transfer an erc20 token from it?

Tags: web3js, gas, python

I have some wallets that have some erc20 tokens that I want to move, but these wallets currently do not have etherum for the gas, so I started writing a program to handle this. The idea is to load the private key and then estimate the amount of etherum that I need to transfer into in order to transfer the erc20 tokens. The issue that I am having is that I seem to be having difficulty figuring out how much etherum to send. It works sometimes, and then other times the transaction fails with this error:

```
ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'insufficient funds for gas * price + value'}
```

It doesn't happen all of the time, rather probably half the time. I posted a full log of what is going on here: https://termbin.com/hxn1

It does not make sense to me because there is always ETH leftover after I send the tokens, so why is it claiming that there is not enough eth for gas?

My program is written in python and I am using web3. I am sending erc20 like:

```
unicorns = self.web3.eth.contract(address=contact_address, abi=EIP20_ABI)


raw_txn = {
        "from": '0xDb2733F1143D59E2bF096F7Ee6d9cF2f61352F82',
        "gas": 200000,  # 200000
        'maxPriorityFeePerGas': max_priority_fee_per_gas,
        'maxFeePerGas': max_fee_per_gas,
        "to": contact_address,
        "value": "0x0",
        "data": unicorns.encodeABI('transfer', args=(to_address, raw_amount)),
        "nonce": self.web3.eth.getTransactionCount(from_address),
        "chainId": self.web3.eth.chain_id
    }
    signed_txn = self.web3.eth.account.signTransaction(raw_txn, private_key)
    tx = self.web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
```

And of course right now I am testing on testnet till I get this right.
[1]: https://

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this solves the issue:

```
unicorns = self.web3.eth.contract(address=contact_address, abi=EIP20_ABI)
est = unicorns.functions.transfer(to_address, raw_amount).estimateGas({'from': '0xDb2733F1143D59E2bF096F7Ee6d9cF2f61352F82'})
est = self.web3.eth.estimate_gas(raw_txn)

signed_txn = self.web3.eth.account.signTransaction(raw_txn, private_key)
ret = self.web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
```